# Preventing pandas from coercing datetime.timedelta to numpy.timedelta64 during Series operations?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I am attempting to parse a large set of keystroke data, and have run into a datatype challenge trying to create a column for time elapsed between key press and release.

My goal is to create a column of timedeltas of the datetime.timedelta type. The parser flow is as follows:

1. Convert the press and release times from a string to a datetime using pandas.to_datetime; this returns a Timestamp datatype.
2. Subtract the press and release times to get the length of the keypress, as a datetime.timedelta type.
3. (Later) Use the timedelta.total_seconds() method to get the seconds as an integer or float, for further analysis.

I'm running into a problem at step 2 -- when I subtract two individual Timestamps in the interpreter, I get a datetime.timedelta (which is what I want), when I subtract two Series of Timestamps, the resulting Series is the numpy.timedelta64 type! Does anyone know why pandas is returning this datatype for Series subtractions, while I'm getting a datetime.timedelta for individual subtractions?

Thank you so much!

I've pasted my debugging session below, where I first do the conversion manually on a single row, and then the same conversion using Series-wide operators.

**Manually:**

```
In : touchtime = task_dataframe['TouchTime'].ix[0]
In : touchtime
Out[1]: u'07:01:00.891'
In : releasetime = task_dataframe['ReleaseTime'].ix[0]
In : releasetime
Out[1]: u'07:01:00.950'
In : import pandas as pd
In : touchtime = pd.to_datetime(touchtime)
In : touchtime
Out[1]: Timestamp('2014-05-30 07:01:00.891000', tz=None)
In : releasetime = pd.to_datetime(releasetime)
In : releasetime
Out[1]: Timestamp('2014-05-30 07:01:00.950000', tz=None)
In : holdtime = releasetime - touchtime
In : holdtime
Out[1]: datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 59000)
```

**Series-wide:**

```
In : task_dataframe['TouchTime'] = task_dataframe['TouchTime'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
In : task_dataframe['ReleaseTime'] = task_dataframe['ReleaseTime'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
In : releasetime2 = task_dataframe['ReleaseTime'].ix[0]
In : releasetime2
Out[1]: Timestamp('2014-05-30 07:01:00.950000', tz=None) # Same output as above
In : releasetime == releasetime2
Out[1]: True # Showing equivalence
In : task_dataframe['HoldTime'] = task_dataframe['ReleaseTime'] - task_dataframe['TouchTime']
In : holdtime2 = task_dataframe['HoldTime'].ix[0]
In : holdtime2
Out[1]: numpy.timedelta64(59000000,'ns')
In : holdtime == holdtime2
Out[1]: False # Non-equivalent
```

Comment: Could you just do `numpy.int64(task_dataframe['HoldTime'])` to get your integers?

Answer (score 1):

pandas holds `timedelta64[ns]` internally (as a numpy array). This is a *much* more efficient representation (as its basically an integer) for computation.

You can convert frequency [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas).

What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: We'll be doing some statistical analysis on the lengths of the key presses (as well as the time between the key presses), detecting and removing outliers (key presses that are suspiciously long or short), converting the lengths of the presses into some other value (by mapping some function to the entire series), and so on.

Comment: ok, so a Series of ``timedelta64[ns]`` is more efficient at this.